# python logic error

Tags: python

please help me figure out what is wrong with this code; the first function works fine 
but the second one returns the wrong number. what the second variable is sup post to return is the remainder of minutes passed since midnight.

```
 def get_hours(s):
    time=s/3600
    return time

#The get_hour function returns how many hours have passed since midnight. The
# parameter is the time in seconds that has passed since midnight.
def get_minutes_remainder(s):
    hours=get_hours(s)
    minutes=s/60
    a=round(hours)
    b=a-hours
    b=abs(b)
    minutes=minutes*b
    return minutes
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Depending on what the code looks like that is using this, you may want to consider the datetime module.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use floor not round (not to mention some other logic errors):

```
from math import floor
def get_minutes_remainder(s):
    hours = get_hours(s)
    whole_hours = floor(hours)
    fractional_hours = hours - whole_hours
    return fractional_hours * 60
```